# How to do the same with multiprocessing pool and not process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here I am trying to a get a final dictionary where `key` shall be the `file name` and the `value` shall the `number of columns` in that file. I am able to do it with multiprocessing process class. But the main issue here is that I manually have to divide all the files into chunks to give it to process. I would like to use pool, because I don't want to do this exercise. How to use pool and manager both to get the same result ?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
import multiprocessing
import time
all_files = os.listdir('E:\\2nd Set\\')

def rule(files,main_list):
    for file in files:
        df = pd.read_csv('E:\\2nd Set\\'+file)
        main_list[file] = df.shape[0]

if __name__=='__main__':
    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    main_list = mgr.dict()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=rule,args=(all_files[:800],main_list))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=rule,args=(all_files[800:],main_list))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print(main_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work. As I mentioned elsewhere, this may not be the best candidate for either multiprocessing or multithreading unless you have a solid state drive. I have set the pool size to be 2, which make this in essence the equivalent of your original program that uses `Process` instances. You can try increasing the pool size and seeing how that affects performance (see my note at the end about rebooting between successive runs to clear your disk cache to get an accurate timing), but I suspect that it will hurt performance because your disk can only sustain a certain amount of throughput and having multiple processes or threads moving the disk head back and forth as a result of reading files concurrently can only start to hurt performance unless you have a solid state drive. I have also included a multithreading version.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
import multiprocessing
import time
from functools import partial


DIR = 'E:\\2nd Set\\'

def rule(file, main_list):
    df = pd.read_csv(DIR + file)
    main_list[file] = df.shape[0]

if __name__=='__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    all_files = os.listdir(DIR)
    # Move the following statement here so that it is not
    # needlessly computed by each subprocess if this is being
    # run under Windows:
    all_files = os.listdir(DIR)
    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    main_list = mgr.dict()
    # Too many threads or processes can really hurt you because of
    # disk contention. The disk can only support so much concurrent
    # I/O
    MAX_PROCESSES = 2 # The equivalent of the original program
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PROCESSES)
    worker = partial(rule, main_list=main_list)
    pool.map(worker, all_files)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time

    print(main_list)
    print(elapsed)
```

You might try doing this with multithreading and see if the performance improves. But, **you need to reboot your computer first to ensure that any disk cache has been flushed before comparing the timings of multiprocessing vs. multithreading** or any two successive runs of any changes you make to the code. Here is the multithreading version, which can use a regular dictionary:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
from mulitprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time
from functools import partial


DIR = 'E:\\2nd Set\\'

def rule(file, main_list):
    df = pd.read_csv(DIR + file)
    main_list[file] = df.shape[0]

if __name__=='__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    all_files = os.listdir(DIR)
    main_list = {}
    # Too many threads or processes can really hurt you because of
    # disk contention. The disk can only support so much concurrent
    # I/O
    MAX_THREADS = 2 # The equivalent of the original program
    pool = ThreadPool(MAX_THREADS)
    worker = partial(rule, main_list=main_list)
    pool.map(worker, all_files)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time

    print(main_list)
    print(elapsed)
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Well I tried using 16 processes and the system becomes very slow. Since files are stored in system, the process is becoming slow. Do you think it makes sense to store all the data in a dictionary (instead of seperate csv files ) and then run the process ?

Comment: How to reduce the IO bound task in order to use 16 processes here ?